# Different CSS for every box?

Tags: html, css

In my page i have many table cells. 
Inside each cell i have one box (i'm using a spoiler code to show or hide contents inside).
The box is described by a CSS.
The boxes are identical in looks, but I want to customize the properties of each as changing the color or background image
 I paste CSS several times equivalent to the number of boxes.
 I paste css style before each boxes code. 
 I try to change the background image of *each* box (default the color is white) but when i try to change one of these backgrounds, i obtain the same background of ALL boxes. 
But it isn't what I want. 
I have severals pictures in folder but it seems like I can not have different background pictures for different boxes..
 
This is the css style I use.:

```
<style type='text/css'>
            div.myautoscroll {
            height: 80ex;
            width: auto;
            background: white;
            background-image: url(cieloprato.jpg);
            overflow: hidden;
            border: 1px solid #444;
            margin: 1em;
        }
        div.myautoscroll:hover {
            overflow: auto;
        }
        div.myautoscroll p {
            padding-right: 16px;
        }
        div.myautoscroll:hover p {
            padding-right: 0px;
        }


  </style>
```

The background image for 1st box is `cieloprato.jpg`. But i want insert different image for box2 like bastman.png, for box3 spiderman.gif. 
How Can I change background image or CSS style for every box?
Forgive my ignorance

Comment: sorry if i have code not well indented and messy but it is in continuous development and improvement http://pastebin.com/NN3bvk3d

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there are 3 ways:

***Firstly***. You may use `nth-*` css properties, but it does not work in old browsers.

```
.myautoscroll:nth-of-type(2) { 
  background: #3e3;
}
```

This code change background color in 3 div with this class.

***Secondly***. You may add to each `div` element unique `identifier` or `class`, and get it by according selector in css.

```
<div class="myautoscroll" id="mas1">...</div>
<div class="myautoscroll" id="mas2">...</div>

#mas1 {
  ...
}

#mas2 {
  ...
}
```

***Thirdly***. You may add to each `div` element `style` attribute where you point which background you want.

```
<div class="myautoscroll" style="background: #0f3">...</div>
<div class="myautoscroll" style="background: #1f3">...</div>
```

***Fourthly***. You may do this by loop in JavaScript (it is just example):

```
var elements = document.getElementByClassName('myautoscroll');

for (var i in elements) {
  var el = elements[i];
  el.style.background = '#' + (i % 10) + 'f3';
}
```

Comment: Be careful when excluding the type selector from an `:nth-of-type()` selector - it doesn't become `:nth-of-class()` (which doesn't exist) when you add a class selector.

Comment: In this case it doesn't matter since they are all `div` tags, but a general rule of thumb I follow is to make sure I include the tag name when using `:nth-of-type()`, hence `div.myautoscroll:nth-of-type()`.

Comment: i try now this methd but i believe to wrong something because if i change `div.myautoscroll {` with `#mas1 {` it give me upside down images..

Comment: Thanks for help Spransky but i think that is something wrong..this is the output of my html code (look above for source) http://img15.imageshack.us/img15/3984/cssproble.png  Can you figure out what my problem now? I want change background box 2, 3 ,4 ..

Comment: sorry for the delay..I went to sleep..I uploaded the files now. You can find CSSs. Look here: http://chilp.it/ad677d

Comment: i want change the 2nd background but if i try to change it, the css also changes my first background..u can see that background for both boxes is the same `cieloprato.jpg`. I want insert another background for another box. How can modify the code?

Comment: @SperanskyDanil Do you understand what I do?

Comment: I solve the problem, thank for support. <div class="myautoscroll" style="background: #0f3"> is the solution for me.

Answer (score 1):

Why dont you just give the td a class?

```
.box1{background:url(cieloprato.jpg};
.box2{background:url(batman.png)};
```

and put it in the html like this

```
<td class = "box1"></td>
<td class = "box2"></td>
```